# ASP.NET MVC4 : Filter search result in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, search

I have done searching part for a list in a partialView.

[image]

I have multiple partialView in this application as you can see from image.

**So my question**

Whenever I create search filter for a grid then I have to create another view and partialview  to show the success results. How can I show filtered search list within this same partial view and don't need to make a success partialview for that list again?

**I've done-**

Rendering list from database-

```
  public ActionResult _ProductSearchList() {
        List<ProductModel> product;
        product = (from u in db.ProductTables
                   select new ProductModel {
                       productname = u.ProductName,
                       productprice = Convert.ToInt32(u.ProductPrice),
                       productID = u.ProductID,
                       dateaddproduct = Convert.ToDateTime(u.ProductAddDate)

               }).ToList();

    return PartialView(product);
}
```

**Searching for records-**

```
<div>
 <legend>Prducts</legend>
                        <input type="text" id="search-products" />
                        @Html.Action("_ProductSearchList", "LedgerIndex")
</div>
```

**Script for retrieving records-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#search-products').keyup(function () {
            var serachstring = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Product/JsonSearchProduct/?stringSearched=' + serachstring,
                type: 'get',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    JSON.stringify(data);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Json result in controller-**

```
   public JsonResult JsonSearchProduct(string stringSearched) {
            List<ProductModel> product;
            product = (from u in db.ProductTables
                       where u.ProductName.Contains(stringSearched)
                       select new ProductModel {
                           productID = u.ProductID,
                           productname = u.ProductName,
                           productprice = Convert.ToInt32(u.ProductPrice),
                           dateaddproduct = Convert.ToDateTime(u.ProductAddDate)
                       }).ToList();
            return Json(product, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

So when I searched String `M` it retrieves records and showing only records containing `M` in their name.

Now this filtered result as `JSON` is what I want to filter in this same partialView without creating extra partialView.

Comment: Can you not simple re-query the controller with the additional search terms? eg, first search 'M', second search 'Ma'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let the search method return the same partial view:

```
public ActionResult JsonSearchProduct(string stringSearched) 
{
    List<ProductModel> products;
    // Search for products...

    return PartialView("_ProductSearchList", products);
}
```

If you wrap the partial view inside a `div`, you can replace its html with jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $('#search-products').keyup(function () {
        var serachstring = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/JsonSearchProduct/?stringSearched=' + serachstring,
            type: 'get',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // data will contain the html of the partial view.
                $('div#product-grid').html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Note: your Ajax get request can be like this, if you have the JavaScript inside the view:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("JsonSearchProduct", "Product")',
        {
            stringSearched: searchstring
        },
        function (data) {
            $('div#product-grid').html(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: My mistake, Working Now. Thanks